# SQL in Sparx document generation is not working

Tags: sql, enterprise-architect

Im trying to make in EA sparx repository template, for generation document with printed diagram in package and listed all components, notes and mainly packages they are stored.

- Template contain diagram and fragment link.
  [image: Template]
- Fragment contain table of components, notes and package where component is stored.
  [image: Fragment]

Until I had only list of components and notes, everything was working fine. Once I add also package of component (name from t_package), SQL show me error with "conversion the nvarchar value to data type int"

[image: Sparx error]

and wont print table of components at all.

This is even more strange, because SQL command used separately in SQL Scratch pad is working totally fine and give you correct result. I have created a diagram of tables used, but still I don't understand where is problem...

[image: diagram]

How can I fix this?

Observation:
This is working fine:

```
SELECT o1.Name as Component, o1.Note as "Note.Formatted"
from t_diagramobjects do1, t_diagram d1, t_object o1
where do1.diagram_id = d1.diagram_id
and do1.object_id = o1.object_id
and d1.ea_guid = #DIAGRAMID#
and o1.Object_type = 'Component'
order by o1.Name
```

Here is somewhere problem:

```
SELECT o1.Name as Component, p1.Name as "Part.of", o1.Note as "Note-Formatted" 
from t_diagramobjects do1, t_diagram d1, t_object o1, t_package p1
where do1.diagram_id = d1.diagram_id
and o1.Package_ID = p1.Package_ID 
and do1.object_id = o1.object_id
and d1.ea_guid = #DIAGRAMID#
and o1.Object_type = 'Component'
order by "Part.of"
```

Comment: Please don't include images of code. Post the actual SQL code.

Comment: The SQL command is not working fine in SQL Scratchpad, that is not possible.

Comment: Your SQL code doesn't correspond to the image you posted and the error you posted. Also using a dot in a column alias is a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in the line

```
and d1.ea_guid = #DIAGRAMID#
```

`#DIAGRAMID#` will contain the integer id of the diagram, not the GUID of the diagram.

Change that to

```
and d1.Diagram_ID = #DIAGRAMID#
```

A trick to figuring out SQL errors when using EA is to check the file `%appdata%\Sparx Systems\EA\DbError.txt` that is where EA logs all SQL errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! but this is not seem to me be the case. I updated code which is working properly and problematic one...